# Python - Sum of List with multiple rows

Tags: python, list, sum

I am trying to solve this problem where I have to add up the list with multiple lines. But I was unable to find a solution.

**Code:**

```
g = input("Enter the file name:")
infile = open(g,'r')

counter = 0
for lu in infile:
    lu = lu.strip()
    lulu = lu.split(",")
    lulu = [float(i) for i in lulu]


coo = sum(lulu)

print("The sum of your numbers is " + str(coo) + ".")
```

**Current Output:**

```
Enter the file name:nums.txt
[-2.5, 2.0]
[8.0]
[100.0, 3.0, 5.1, 3.7]
[6.5]
The sum of your numbers is 6.5.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Enter the file name:nums.txt
[-2.5, 2.0]
[8.0]
[100.0, 3.0, 5.1, 3.7]
[6.5]
The sum of your numbers is 125.8.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are overwriting `lulu` with each line, at the end it is only printing the sum of the last line.

Try the following:

```
g = input("Enter the file name:")
infile = open(g,'r').read().splitlines() #make infile a list of each line in the file

lulu = [float(j) for i in infile for j in i.split(',')] #split each line by a comma, and append each item, (converted to a float) to the list lulu

coo = sum(lulu)

print("The sum of your numbers is " + str(coo) + ".")
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

In your loop you're constantly replacing `lulu` with the latest line. Which means only `6.5` is kept. Bring the `lulu` list out of the loop, and extend it with each line:

```
g = input("Enter the file name:")
infile = open(g,'r')

lulu = []

counter = 0
for lu in infile:
    lu = lu.strip()
    lu.split(",")
    lulu.extend([float(i) for i in lu])


coo = sum(lulu)

print("The sum of your numbers is " + str(coo) + ".")
```